# Is the likelihood function $L(\theta|X)$ equal to or proportional to $p(X|\theta)$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayesian

Sometimes I find that the likelihood function is written as $L(\theta|X)=p(X|\theta)$ while other times $L(\theta|X)\propto p(X|\theta)$.

which is correct?

If $L(\theta|X)\propto p(X|\theta)$, then what is the constant?

Comment: If you're going to post the same question simultaneously on multiple forums, please given the link to the other forum.  For this question the link is https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/582910/is-the-likelihood-function-l-thetax-equal-to-or-proportional-to-px-theta.  And it's been closed in that forum as a duplicate.

Comment: @JimB his question wasn't answered there either, and I don't think it is a duplicate

Comment: @gbd You have a different opinion than the folks who closed the question.  The other issue that simultaneously posting on different forums without such an acknowledgment can waste the time of the folks proving help as they are not aware of any previous answers or helpful comments.  Not a good practice to bite the hand that feeds you.

Comment: @JimB his question is about proportionality vs equality relationship between probability and likelihood... And I dont see that answered in any thread.

Comment: @gbd You might want to advise the OP to clarify the question at CrossValidated to see if the question could be re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

In one sense, it doesn't matter. The absolute value of the likelihood doesn't mean much, it's the likelihood *ratio* that is what is actually useful.

Typically, you normalize the likelihood function $L(\theta|x)$ by dividing by $L(\theta^*|x) = \max_{\theta} L(\theta|x)$ to get the standard likelihood ratio.

The likelihood ratio as developed above is quite useful. A very powerful/useful asymptotic result called Wilks Theorem defines the null distribution of the log-likelihood ratio. We use it to find the range $\theta$ that cannot be rejected in favor of the MLE.

The most general statement is $L(\theta|x) \propto p(\theta|x)$, since that encompasses but doesn't require, strict equality.